# Symfony 2 can't load AuthenticatedVoter

Tags: php, symfony

I changed location of my Sf2 project from localhost to server. On my machine all works properly but on server I get in log:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: "Attempted to load class "AuthenticatedVoter" from namespace "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter". Did you forget a "use" statement for another namespace?" at /var/www/vhosts/27/167865/webspace/httpdocs/app/cache/prod/appProdProjectContainer.php line 1176

What is the point of that problem?

Comment: how did you transfer your sf2? ftp / git + composer? did you launch composer install command?

Comment: I transfer files by ftp and didn't launch composer command.

Answer (score 0):

try to clear cache

```
php app/console cache:clear

php app/console cache:clear --env=prod
```